# Add redirect URL to B2C application not using the portal

Tags: azure, azure-automation

Im trying to automate the release of a new front-end app for my B2C application and I can automate everything until I get to the point of needing to specify a new B2C redirect.

Is this possible to do via code?

Comment: Are you asking about creating a new Azure AD application in B2C and setting its redirect URI?

Comment: Can you answer above question first? Then we can help you further.

Comment: Apologies,  no same Application but automatically adding a redirect URL

Comment: @whatisthejava which development language do you use?